# Нескоро или не скоро?

Tags: частица-не

Как правильно писать: "не скоро" или "нескоро"? Или есть и тот, и тот вариант?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если перед причастием стоят слова *совершенно, очень, крайне, чрезвычайно, совсем*, то пишется слитно - "нескоро".
Пример: *"Очень нескоро он смог спокойно спать по ночам"*.
В остальных случаях пишется раздельно.
Пример: *"Скоро сказка сказывается, да не скоро дело делается"*.

Comment: "Если перед причастием стоят слова" - о каком причастии речь?..

Answer (score 6):

В некоторых случаях возможно двоякое толкование текста и, как следствие, двоякое написание; ср.: до ближайшей остановки автобуса отсюда недалеко (утверждается, что близко) – до ближайшей остановки автобуса отсюда не далеко (отрицается, что далеко); редактор уехал ненадолго (на короткое время) – редактор уехал не надолго (не на продолжительное время).

нескоро - утверждается, что нескоро (долго)
не скоро - отрицается, что скоро