# «Нескоро» или «не скоро»?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, наречия

*Нескоро суждено им встретиться вновь.*
Как правильно написать *нескоро* в этом предложении?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нескоро или не скоро?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/93/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be)

Answer (score 2):

Медленно, небыстро, неторопливо... Три наречия-синонима есть у слова *нескоро*, хотя ни один не вписывается в заданный контекст и здесь смысл *нескоро* не может быть выражен так же кратко и без редактирования фразы (допустим: «Не той осенью суждено им было встретиться вновь»). Тем не менее...

О частице *не* с наречиями читаем у Розенталя: «Пишется раздельно частица *не* с наречиями на *-о*, если имеется или подразумевается противопоставление (живут не богато, а бедно; обычно ехали не быстро и не медленно; не часто возникает подобная ситуация; **не скоро** ещё вскроется река).

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81&ysclid=l6yvmxex1b603269633

Comment: Извините, но так и не поняла — слитно или раздельно надо писать в нашем предложении?

Comment: Несмотря на трудность и обречённость выбора нужного слова как подразумеваемого противопоставления (см. первый абзац), следует прислушаться к рекомендации из Розенталя о раздельном письме частицы *не* с наречиями на *-о*.

Answer (score 2):

*Правильно: **Не скоро суждено им встретиться вновь.***

Пояснение

1. Интересно, что современный словарь предлагает **одну форму письма:**

Орфографический словарь РАН ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE&all=x)): **не скоро,** *нареч.* (спустя долгий срок)

В то же время частотность формы "нескоро" в Нацкорпусе значительно выше.

2. Более логичным было бы наличие двух форм, но **в начале предложения** раздельное написание встречается чаще (обычно в этих случаях первое слово выделено **логическим ударением**).
3. **У Розенталя** обозначено такое [правило](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81): Пункт 3. Пишется раздельно частица НЕ с наречиями на -о, если **имеется или подразумевается противопоставление**: живут не богато, а бедно; обычно ехали не быстро и не медленно; **не часто** возникает подобная ситуация; **не скоро** ещё вскроется река; **не случайно** он завёл этот разговор; **не вечно** будет природа хранить свои тайны от человека; **не сладко** жилось переселенцам на первых порах; Говоря честно, **не много** найдётся людей, которые не испытывают неприятного чувства при виде пауков.
4. **Пример:** Но этому желанию **не скоро** суждено было сбыться. [В. П. Мещерский. Мои воспоминания (1897)]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** [Вопрос № 235970](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE)
Слитно или нет пишется слово "нескоро"?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Возможно слитное и раздельное написание в зависимости от значения. Пишется слитно наречие *нескоро* в значении "медленно". Например, у Пушкина: ***Нескоро** ели предки наши*. Но раздельно пишется наречие *не скоро* в значении "спустя долгий срок": *Дождь кончится **не скоро***.

**2.** Из одного ответа:
«Медленно, небыстро, неторопливо... Три наречия-синонима есть у слова *нескоро*...»

> 2. Пишется слитно частица ***не*** с наречиями на -о, которые в сочетании с отрицательной частицей приобретают противоположное значение (обычно такие слова можно заменить синонимами без *не*): *неплохо* (ср. *хорошо*); *немного* (ср. *мало*); *неудачно* (ср. *безуспешно*).

*Небыстро* и *неторопливо* не являются синонимами без "не", только *медленно* и *тихо*, но к нашему контексту они никак не подходят.

**3.** Итоги:
без «не» у «не скоро» в нашем предложении подходящий синоним отсутствует;
по контексту имеет значение «спустя долгий срок»;
« не скоро» пишется раздельно.

*Дети* [*sic*] *это сумасшедшие, которым выздороветь **суждено не скоро*** (К. Чуковский).

*К сожалению, эта мечта, которую я лелею каждый год в октябре, до сих пор не сбылась, и, может быть, ей **не скоро суждено** сбыться* (Э. Золя; перевод Б. Эткинда).

Comment: Не скоро ели предки наши,
Не скоро двигались кругом
Ковши, серебряные чаши
С кипящим пивом и вином. https://ilibrary.ru/text/440/p.2/index.html  Какая редакция правильная? Опять же словарь РАН дает одну форму письма, а это закон, а не рекомендация Грамоты.

Comment: В комментариях к ТД 2021 года даются те же рекомендации. *14-16. Пап, а ты ведь ещё не скоро умрёшь? – спросила она. Папа улыбнулся. – Не скоро, – пообещал он. В данном случае не скоро может писаться только раздельно, так как выражает отрицание близости наступления определённого момента – выступает в значении ‘не сейчас, не в ближайшем будущем’, ‘спустя долгий срок’ [АКАДЕМОС]. В предложении 14 это значение подчёркивается сочетанием с частицей ещё. Ср.: слитное нескоро, обозначающее ‘медленно, неторопливо’: Нескоро ели предки наши (Пушкин) [БТС].* Где же ж мне тягаться с "Грамотой" или БТС?

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое ТД 2021.  Меня удивляет решение словаря РАН, мне неясно, какая редакция поэмы Пушкина считается сейчас правильной. Не очень понятны отношения слов «быстрый» и «скорый»,  но значение течения времени в большей степени выражает "скорый". Медленный – антоним к быстрый (скорость процессов).  Наречие «не быстро» пишется только  раздельно по словарю, но в современных текстах много вариантов "небыстро", причем особой разницы в значениях не видно. В общем, разобраться с темой сложно, пишут как кому нравится, по интуиции вероятно.

Comment: Так что с кем или с чем вам "тягаться," я не очень представляю. Формальные подстановки всякого рода, как мне кажется, популярностью в современном письме не пользуются. Так как нет ясного понимания, нет четких правил, то пользователи решают вопрос самостоятельно. Посмотрела этимологию слов: «скорый»  появился чуть раньше «быстрого» (9 – 11век) со значением быть резвым, спешить. Иногда заменяют друг друга, а иногда нет.

Comment: ТД — это тотальный диктант.